# Stored Procedure to create columns from resultset

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have resultset which contains 600 records, now i want to create a new table using stored procedure where that records will be the columns for my new table. How to do this?

Comment: I am using mysql database. is there any pivot functions in mysql?

Comment: you can use temp table for that in store procedures

Comment: @POHH can you please share code snippet.